# Edit sql field type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table who is filled by thousands of registers, so I don´t want to affect them. I want to change type of column:

Table:

```
-----------------
TrainingHours
-----------------
Id int(Primary key)
Hours decimal(18,0)
```

in SQL I can just add design table and changed it manually, but I need to change it with script code to get something like

```
Hours decimal(18,2) //instead (18,0)
```

How can I make this change without sql designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alter table

```
ALTER TABLE TrainingHours ALTER COLUMN Hours decimal(18,2)
```

Comment: I know I can use it, but it doesn´t affect any rows of my table?

Comment: alter column is for column  so affect all the rows .. .. you can't  alter only a rows

Comment: Sure it will. If you have a value of 123,456,789,012,345,678 I believe the first 12 will be truncated.  You could alter it to (20,2) to retain large values if you have them however.  the first # represents the total #'s allowed the 2nd number represents the # of digits to the right of the decimal.

Comment: @xQbert   correct .. the OP  must expand  the  format

Comment: what you meaning about affect all rows?. For example now I have value 1.00 if I change it to 18,2 I get different number? I have simple numbers like 1,4,5 etc, I just want to received 1.5,1.20 etc

Comment: No your example would be fine.  any row numbers over 16 digits to the left of the decimal would be impacted  if you have no such value then you're fine.  you could easily check by writing a query `Select count(1) from traininghours where hours >= 1000000000000000` if count other than 0 returns, then you should probably do 20,2 on the alter instead of 18,2.

Comment: 1.00 remain 1.00 like correctly say xQbert

Comment: Excelent!, and sorry about the question, change is for production API, so I need to secure my change there

Comment: Always unit test locally, apply to test envt, then move to prod!

Comment: Never apply a change into production without first having occurred in a test environment .consistent with the production environment

Comment: Yes, I´m use a copy of db in test server and it works fine!, thankyou guys!

Comment: @Carl  well if my answer i correct please mark it as accepted ..